# Is it appropriate to delete "what has been tried" in a question after receiving an answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question

A couple of days ago I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105729/binary-search-tree-ienumerator-movenext-non-recursive-in-order-traversal-imple) on how to implement an `enumerator.MoveNext()` method for a binary search tree.

Now in order to show that I have thought about the topic, I go quite deep into explaining what I have tried, and why that doesn't work, to the point of question being quite long. I feel like the question and its answer really bring good value to the community, yet because it is that long, people won't generally bother reading it.

I feel like the question could be very simple indeed such as a simple one sentence. Is it appropriate to delete the "what have I tried" in order to make everything much more clearer?

Comment: I dont' think that question is long enough to warrant removing the "what i tried" portion.

Comment: @KevinB - yet I still feel like the question could simply be a one liner.

Comment: IMHO the length of your question is fine. Also the ratio between explanation and code looks good.

Comment: Good questions show research effort. You don't want to delete your research effort just because you got an answer. Being able to see how the OP approached the problem when/before they got stuck is useful for future visitors.

Comment: If you trim the question back to a one-liner, then someone in the future might downvote it for appearing to lack research or effort. If I encounter an old, bad post, I will happily downvote it. (The only exceptions I can think of are that the question is so old there were few rules at the time, and it is perhaps unfair to apply today's _Meta_ rules to something from 2009).

Comment: If you think this question is too long, then you've only been reading questions that are way too short. And there are plenty of those on SO.

Comment: One additional issue - Including the "what I tried" information increases the chances that someone with a similar problem will find your question sooner with a google search.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

TL;DR Don't. But you could put a TL;DR at the top of your post.

First, your research shows approaches that don't work. That's important information. It saves others from trying the same.

Second, as has been pointed out in the comments, good questions show research effort. If a question does not show research effort, it will be considered one more of the dumps from a lazy user who couldn't be bothered to do their homework before posting. It will get downvotes and maybe even close votes. Lack of research effort is not a reason to close, but people sometimes VTC them all the same. (Whether or not they should is a heated debate).

Third, I've seen editors do this to *other* people's posts. Making the posts from other people look like effortless dumps. I'm sure these editors had good intentions, but it was still a wrong move. If people remove the shown effort from their own posts, these editors could take the wrong example - thinking such edits, on their own posts or that of others, are the right thing to do.
I'll grant that this is not a big risk, thank goodness, but it's still a risk.

On the other hand... sometimes the shown research isn't *that* important for future visitors. They want the answer ASAP and don't want to wade through a long article.

So, the best edit is that you try to get the problem across in the first paragraph. The sooner a reader can determine if a question is about the same problem they are facing, the better. Only after they have decided that the post is applicable to their own situation, do the details become relevant.
I somewhat jokingly put a quasi-recursive TL;DR at the top of this post to illustrate it. In reality, using a TL;DR may be a bit too much on Stack Exchange sites, but getting to the point ASAP is key.

Comment: TL;DR +1 for following your own advice. That and, you know, it's pretty solid advice.

Comment: // , I frequently search using keywords from approaches that have failed me. If the failed approaches get removed, it takes away some of my ability to map "code that don't work" to "code that works", or to think creatively about possibilities when I see questions whose answers don't fit mine.  Definitely include a summary at the top, but the longer, the better, for those of us who use our erroneous code to find better code.

Comment: Also: do **not** put the TL;DR at the bottom... people will *not* reach bottom if it's really TL... the TL;DR is meant to be a quick summary to understand what's all about and should be immediately visible.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's better to leave the code, since it's not too long. It may also be valuable as a starting point for people who want to do the same thing. Also, when your question becomes old, and the answers obsolete, the information will be helpful in updating the answers.

Ideally, you should take the time to reorganize your question. The structure isn't too bad, but there's certainly room for improvement.

There are things that should be removed (if they weren't already), like:

- *As you can see...*
- *I am really lost here.*
- *I've tried everything!*
- *I've been trying to fix this forever!*
- *I've searched everywhere* (Stack Overflow, Google, etc.) *for the solution, but found no answer!*
- *I'm a beginner to `X` programming...*

I took the first two from your question, but the others are examples I have run into in other questions. When I run into this type of commentary in old questions, I edit it out. There may be some arguments for leaving it in at first, but after a while it's guaranteed to be no longer relevant to the question (if it was ever relevant).

Answer (score 5):

Consider this not too unlikely scenario:

- Someone posts a question with their various attempts to solve the problem.
- Someone posts an answer that seems to solve the question. The OP tries it once and it works.
- The OP accepts the answer.
- Someone else goes on an edit spree to remove all seemingly irrelevant attempts from the question.
- Further down the road, the OP gets some error. Further research shows that the answer actually didn't solve the problem at all, it just seemed to work. At the same time, more experienced users are calling out that accepted answer as incorrect.
- The OP unchecks the answer as accepted, posts a comment: "no this doesn't work, because..."
- Someone else comes across the thread and starts asking "did you try x?". Which the OP did, it was originally part of the question.
- Long, cluttered comment conversation between the OP and the new person follows. The OP re-posts all their research effort in comments.
- Yet another person comes across the thread and starts yelling at the OP for poor research effort and down votes the question.

This is how you turn perfectly fine questions into crap threads that are hard to follow, or that can't even get salvaged.

Answer (score 3):

No.

You tried all the things described to gain some insight into the problem, and although the things you tried didn't work they gave you further understanding of the problem. That's valuable information for you and for others and shouldn't be discarded lightly.

Answer (score -4):

**I am personally in favor of editing *unnecessary* content out of questions after they have been answered.**

I really dislike scrolling through long questions with lots of details when I already know from the title that this is probably what I want. I almost never read such questions. I skip down to the answers to see if they actually do solve my problem.

Often times the details are necessary when first writing the question in order to prove to other people that you have done your research and have already tried but failed to solve it yourself. However, once you become aware of the answer, you may very well find that some of the code your originally posted was irrelevant to the solution. I say take it out. (I am not speaking to your specific example, just to the general case.)

Also, if a question has Update 1, Update 2, Update 3, and Update 4 detailing all the gory details of unsuccessful attempts, couldn't those be removed or summarized into a short paragraph? Who wants to scroll through all that a year later, let alone read it?

I am hesitant to make such edits to other people's questions, but I definitely think it is something I should consider doing to my own questions, especially those with high traffic.

Comment: // , What about the people who _find_ the post by searching based on their own erroneous approaches?

Comment: I can't speak for everyone, but in my own experience of searching for answers among thousands of questions, I find answers based on key words in the title and tags. I don't know how much of the question text gets it to the top of a Google search, but if the title and a few sentences of the question make it sound remotely similar to my problem, I upvote the question and then skip down to see if any of the answers work. I spend almost zero time analyzing the OP's original problem. I guess I am not the only one since I frequently see highly voted questions with low voted accepted answers.

Comment: @Suragch - I pretty much agree with you and that's exactly why I was asking. I believe we all simply tend to skip trough most of the text, ignoring the walls of text, looking for a solution. Seems like editing the question to omit some text is favorable though. Maybe a better question would be I"s it approriate to edit / shorten the question after receiving an answer."

Comment: I get where you guys are coming from, but I agree with the people saying that that stuff should be preserved. However, it would be nice if SO had "spoiler" buttons that could fold and hide those gory details.

Comment: @PM2Ring - the "spoiler" feature is a great idea imo

Comment: @PM2Ring, I also like this idea. My complaint is having to scroll through long questions that most people don't read. This would make the question short while still preserving the details for those who want it. There could even be expandable sections for code, research, updates, etc., which would also help newer users organize their questions better.